# convert textarea input to javascript object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

bit of a junior dev here, i have a text area which will receive an input of an array of objects like so ..

```
[
  {
     utc: "xxxxxx",
     battery_level: 12,
     lat: 2345678,
     lng: 234567,
   },
   {
     utc: "xxxxxx",
     battery_level: 12,
     lat: 2345678,
     lng: 234567,
    }
]
```

the text area input converts it to string like..

```
'[\n  {\n     utc: "xxxxxx",\n     battery_level: 12,\n… 12,\n     lat: 2345678,\n     lng: 234567,\n    }\n]'
```

i need to convert that back to a javascript object. i have tried JSON.parse which throw an error 'unexpected token u at position 10' the u of utc because it is NOT a string key.

i have tried JSON.stringify to JSON.parse which still returns a string.

the project is using react with typescript. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the JavaScript objects may or may not have quotes, while the JSON standard requires double quotes for each property name.

For this reason, you cannot use `JSON.parse`, since that is not a valid JSON.

You have three alternatives:

- Create a parser that converts your string into an object (zero dep.)
- Use `eval`, which would introduce vulnerabilities. You said that users can paste anything into the textbox, so the use of `eval` is highly discouraged
- Use [JSON5](https://github.com/json5/json5)

Indeed, JSON5 does exactly what you need to do:

```
JSON5.parse('[\n  {\n     utc: "xxxxxx",\n     battery_level: 12,\n… 12,\n     lat: 2345678,\n     lng: 234567,\n    }\n]')
```